# NextAuth Google Provider NEXTAUTH_URL not being used

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I am currently implementing NextAuth into a NextJS 13 application. The only provider I am using is Google. When running the app locally everything works fine - I click the "sign in with Google" button and it takes me to the "Choose an account to continue to X" screen, I select an account and the session is created.

I am trying to deploy it to Vercel, but when I click on the "sign in with Google" button I get sent to `https://undefined/api/auth/signin?csrf=true`. I suspected this was due to a miss configured environment variable but according to the [NextAuth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/deployment#vercel) it uses the `VERCEL_URL` instead of the `NEXTAUTH_URL`. I have ticked the "Automatically expose System Environment Variables" box. Since I don't even get to a Google-hosted page I don't think it is to do with my clientID/ClientSecret.

I have NextAuth working using NextJS 12 but this project uses the app directory, which is the only difference as far as I can see. Is there a possible workaround for this? Thank you.

Comment: Check these two threads: 
- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7289
- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7229

Comment: Thank you for pointing these out to me. By removing the vercel environment variables and defining them myself the redirect has now stoped all together. I will continue to look though the issues.